# Can a white noise process be predicted?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, modeling, model, white-noise

I'm trying to better understand why white noise processes can't be predicted. I understand that these processes have mean zero and no correlaation between it's values at different times. I'm looking for a more in-depth answer however as to why it's impossible to forecast/predict these types of processes. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it can be predicted. You write yourself that white noise has a certain mean (it does not have to be zero), so we have an expectation point forecast. Similarly, we may know the distribution, so we can give a density forecast. If your question is why we cannot predict the next value perfectly, then the answer is that there is residual noise.

Comment: It’s not that we can’t predict them, just that there is a limit to how accurately we can predict the values.